# MVC code does not calling API method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

MVC controller method

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetCJTDLitigantCases(string searchKey)
    {
        var requestUri = cjtdkioskhearingsURI + "?searchKey=" + Server.UrlEncode(searchKey) + "&departmentId=" + _departmentId;
        var result = string.Empty;
        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        var response = await _webApiClient.GetAsyncV2(requestUri);

        if (VerifyResponse(response, out errorMessage))
        {

            var kioskCJTDCaseSearchModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KioskHearingInfoMinimalModel>
                                          (await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            ViewBag.partyInformation = searchKey;
           //ViewBag.departmentId = departmentId;
            return await Task.FromResult<ViewResult>(View("SelectPartyType", kioskCJTDCaseSearchModel));
        }

        else
        {
            return View("Error", errorMessage);
        }

    }
```

API method

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsyncV2(string searchKey, int departmentId)
    {
        _logger.TraceLog();

        if (searchKey != string.Empty && departmentId <= 0)
        {
            var badRequestResponse = this.Request.CreateResponse<ErrorModel>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new ErrorModel
            {
                ErrorKey = ErrorKeys.InvalidInput
            }, MediaTypeFormats.Json);

            return await Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(badRequestResponse);
        }

        try
        {
            var HearingDetails = await _caseActions.GetHearingBySearchkey(searchKey, departmentId);
            var successResponse =
                this.Request.CreateResponse<CJTDKioskHearingModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, HearingDetails, MediaTypeFormats.Json);

            return await Task.FromResult<HttpResponseMessage>(successResponse);
        }
        catch (EntityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex);

            return this.Request.CreateResponse<ErrorModel>(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new ErrorModel
            {
                ErrorKey = ErrorKeys.EntityNotFound
            }, MediaTypeFormats.Json);
        }
        catch (DependencyNotFoundException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex);

            return this.Request.CreateResponse<ErrorModel>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ErrorModel
            {
                ErrorKey = ErrorKeys.DependecyNotFound
            }, MediaTypeFormats.Json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex);

            return this.Request.CreateResponse<ErrorModel>(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new ErrorModel
            {
                ErrorKey = ErrorKeys.ServerError
            }, MediaTypeFormats.Json);
        }
    }
```

Comment: "does not calling", so what does it say instead? Does it give any error?

Comment: no..its not giving an error..it does not giving call to my api method..i have also given route prefix to api controller..even though it doesnt calling api method i.e.getasyncv2

Comment: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcR2l0YS5WZWVyXFN0YXRlQ291cnRzX0NRTVNcU291cmNlXFN0YXRlQ291cnRzLkFQSVxhcGlcdjJcY2p0ZGtpb3NraGVhcmluZ3M=?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 07:41:41 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1491
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}            ----this resonse error is given it doesnt calling api method

Comment: So that could be error at server side, have you checked your logs at server side?

Comment: yes i checked it does not showing any error in error log

Comment: You can add logs at first line of action method to check if your API method was called!

Comment: Try enabling exceptions (to catch all) on the application containing the API method - this should break on the issue and you'll be able to find out more information.

Comment: @Mukesh Modhvadiya : Thanks

Comment: @ Phil Cooper: Thanks